# Android Studio: Try-catch exception crashes application

Tags: java, android, exception

I was testing some vulnerabilities inside of my code and trying to fix them by throwing an exception when the user has an invalid input. Now when I implement a try-catch and run the application on my phone, it crashes when I put in that invalid input.

I assume my code doesn't catch the exception from the addData method. Is there another way to implement exceptions or how can I make it possible to catch the exception from the addData method?

```
package com.odisee.photoboothapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.odisee.photoboothapp.fontchanger.FontChangeTextView;

public class Form_Database extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;

int selectedId;
RadioGroup test;
RadioButton editEducation;
EditText editName, editSurname, editEmail;
Button btnAddData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form__database);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    test = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonChoice);

    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);
    editSurname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_Surname);
    editEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_Email);


    btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    try {
        addData();
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Toast.makeText(Form_Database.this,"Data not inserted" + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void addData() {
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(editName.getText().toString().contains("DROP")) {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("SQL Exceptie!");
                        }
                        else {

                            selectedId = test.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            editEducation = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
                            boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(), editSurname.getText().toString(), editEmail.getText().toString(), editEducation.getText().toString());

                            sendEmail();

                            if(isInserted == true) {
                                Toast.makeText(Form_Database.this,"Data inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(Form_Database.this,"Data not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
    );
}

public void sendEmail() {
    //Getting content for email
    String email = editEmail.getText().toString();
    String subject = "testberichtje voor lorenzo";
    String message = "testberichtje voor lorenzo";

    //Creating SendMail object
    SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

    //Executing sendmail to send email
    sm.execute();
}

}
```

> 05-01 17:58:17.021 30232-30232/com.odisee.photoboothapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.odisee.photoboothapp, PID: 30232
>                                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SQL Exceptie!
>                                                                                 at com.odisee.photoboothapp.Form_Database$1.onClick(Form_Database.java:55)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
>                                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Crash with what error? Unless it's a syntax error, the try/catch itself won't cause a crash.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The gradle file of my application builds perfectly. The app ran perfectly before putting in the exception. So it can't be something else than that. if I put in the String "DROP" inside of my forms input line and click the "SEND" button. it just crashes and says "Nameapp has stopped.".

Comment: Can you please upload the stack trace? It's basically impossible to tell what could be wrong

Comment: @ParthBhoiwala uploaded it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're not wrapping your exception prone code in the `try-catch` clause. You've set an `OnClickListener` to a `Button` and this is the only part that's being tested.

The actual button presses are asynchronous, and they don't take place in the tested block of code.

Actually you don't need an exception here - exceptions should not be used to control normal application flow. In your case all you should do is to display a `Toast` that explains to a user that they have used a forbidden keyword.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that! It's the first application that I am programming an Android application. Still have to learn a lot when it comes to creating a decent, safe and good program flow/code. 

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 5):

Try making the catch more generic so you can actually catch the error, then print the stack trace so you can see the issue:

```
try{
    //Try to do something on here
}catch(Exception error1) {
    Log.e(TAG, "The exception caught while executing the process. (error1)")
    error1.printStackTrace();
}
```